# Views from old fragment remain in content view after the fragment is replaced

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-permissions

I have came across a peculiar bug : in my application I have bottom navigation bar that replaces the fragments in FrameLayout view using a following piece of code:

```
override fun setFragment(frag: Fragment, addToBackStack: Boolean) {
    FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this).setCurrentScreen(this, frag::class.java.simpleName, frag::class.java.simpleName)
    val ft = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out, R.anim.fragment_in, R.anim.fragment_out)
            .replace(R.id.container, frag)

    if (addToBackStack) {
        viewModel.showNavigation = false
        ft.addToBackStack(null)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
    }

    ft.commit()
}
```

Everything seems to work fine - but for a one fragment in which in onCreateView method I call the following method:

```
override fun requestPermissions(permissions: Array<String>, requestCode: Int) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        activity.requestPermissions(permissions, requestCode)
}
```

This causes the view from the previous fragment to remain on screen and new fragment to be added **below** them, as seen in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What's worse, the views will stay in the screen until the activity is killed. The only workaround I was able to find was adding a 0,5 second delay before asking for permission:

```
Handler().postDelayed({ requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, requestCode = REQUEST_PERMISSION_LOCATION) }, 500L)
```

My question is - **does anyone know what is the cause of this behaviour and if there's a better way to circumvent it**?

Comment: set Background color for your layout

Comment: @ysl Tried that, it didn't work - besides the new fragment is added below the old views.

Comment: can i see your code for activity

Comment: @ysl Yes, I posted it to pastebin, can be found here:
https://pastebin.com/rq1JJKfd

Comment: Whichever is your home fragment i.e fragment which is visible at time your main activity launches that should .add then all other fragments should be .replace

Comment: @ysl From what I found in Android source code calling replace is effectively the same as using remove and than add methods, with fragment currently attached to content view as the argument for the first method. And since remove method just would do nothing when you pas null value to it, there seems to be no difference between calling replace and add.
(sourcecode for reference : http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/4.3_r2-robolectric-0/android/app/BackStackRecord.java#BackStackRecord.Op)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for me was to set the background color in the `xml` file as suggested in the original question comments by @Yolo.

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

After I made this change, pieces of this fragment didn't hang around anymore when I switched to new fragments.